# orderBySortDescriptor not calling selector

Tags: objective-c, parsing, sorting, nsarray

The selector compareUserObject:toObject: is never called and the array is only sorted by comparing status with a simple equality check.  The query is a Parse query.  How do I get my custom comparator(compareUserObject:toObject:) to be called?

```
 NSSortDescriptor *statusDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                      initWithKey:@"status"
                                      ascending:NO
                                      selector:@selector(compareUserObject:toObject:)];

[query orderBySortDescriptor:statusDescriptor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because you 're passing 2 parameters to it. Look at this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSortDescriptor/initWithKey:ascending:selector:

"The method to use when comparing the properties of objects, for example caseInsensitiveCompare: or localizedCompare:. The selector must specify a method implemented by the value of the property identified by keyPath. **The selector used for the comparison is passed a single parameter**, the object to compare against self, and must return the appropriate NSComparisonResult constant. The selector must 
have the same method signature as:"

```
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCompare:(NSString *)aString
```